# Is there a double-contact banana plug?

Tags: connector, banana-jack

I want to create a kids toy, where is a CPLD (like GAL22V10D) taken as a sample, so I need to shorts column lines and row lines with some big connector. It will be most obvious and accessibly if the user stick this big connector into the holes.

I am trying to find a double-contact banana plug which can be used to connect two holes on two separate boards together, shoveing a banana jack into a plated hole in a thick (2 mm) circuit board.

[image]

I found a [male-to-male banana plug](https://www.ebay.ph/itm/275252166473?hash=item40164ebf49:g:vpQAAOSwMOxdA13Z), but it has spherical ends so the extraction of this plug from two connected holes seems hard.

[image]

Is there a double-contact banana plug with one contact on the end and one contact on the side?

Comment: Ordinarily, banana jacks would not be used as board-to-board connectors (or, really, for anything other than cables). I'm also not sure what you mean by "one contact on the side"-- are you looking for the thing you posted, but L-shaped? What is your use case? Why the 4mm jacks?

Comment: "are you looking for the thing you posted, but L-shaped" No, I am looking the connector that can be equiped with a handle to extraction from two holes. The connector on the picture has contacts on the ends, so it can not be equiped with a handle. I need a similar connector but its sectond contact should be not in the end, but in the middle. And its second end should has some bracing for handle.

Comment: I still can't understand what sort of a thing you're looking for, and I don't know what your use case is, so I'll bow out and hopefully someone else will do better. I will say, though, that the choice of board-to-board connector is generally given by the relative orientation of the boards, the mechanical strength required, and the way in which they need to be assembled; and I cannot conceive of a situation where banana plugs would be the best option.

Comment: I add a picture to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to just shove a banana jack into a plated hole in a circuit board?  Banana jacks are designed to go into a _tube_.  Are you saying you want a two-circuit banana jack?  Those don't exist (or if they do they're not at all common).  Please _edit your question_ to clarify what you're _actually doing_.

Comment: @Arseniy I think the best option you're going to find is either to get some male-female domino/phoenix connectors which would be my preference for connecting two boards vertically in a children's toy. If you really want something so simple the kid just has to stick a big fat plug into a hole, 1/4" telephone jack and see my comments below. The phoenix terminal is just much more robust and is used in commercial settings where government workers (who are essentially just big children) have to interact with the product. It's damn hard to snap a phoenix, cause a short, or break the housing.

Answer (score 4):

Of course there isn't. This goes against every design principle according to the era during which banana jacks were invented.

When they wanted the functionality you're talking about, they invented the 1/4" telephone jack.

There are dual banana plugs, rarely quad banana plugs. Space wasn't at a premium back then. Components were huge, and consequently panels could accommodate many holes for single-conductor connectors.

Why can't you just use a stereo telephone jack? If you need more current or better RF performance then you have DIN connectors.

I fail to see any requirement that a stereo banana plug could satisfy that can't be satisfied better by common options.

The photo you linked is called a gender changer. It is used to make a female banana jack into a banana plug. It's not supposed to be easy to separate. It can be used as a coupler, yes. But this is only in the case that one of your banana jacks require a gender change into a plug. In which case one of your jacks is going to separate quite easily when you pull, leaving the other with it's gender still changed. And you'll have a harder time separating the gender changer from this end.

Also remember that the banana jack is still one of the most well-respected connectors with respect to surface area contact and oxygen-free connection. It is literally made to minimize skin effect resistance.

This feature is entirely dependent on the spring-loaded plug sides. The tip would offer completely asymmetric qualities with respect to the connection on the side. This is again in contrast to the 1/4" telephone jack, which offers symmetric connection design.

A typical coupler is male - female ( >-— )

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have two boards stacked on top of each other with a banana jack on each and a plug with two sets of contacts that plugs into it from the top and goes through the top board's jack and then into the bottom board's jack.

I highly doubt such a thing exists. Also, you would need jacks that would allow the plug to go all the way through and stick out the other side, and I can't say I've ever seen that either.

In electronics, when you find yourself looking for something like a connector that doesn't exist it's often because there's no use case for it. This is a case of what we call an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), you're trying to fit a solution to a problem instead of the other way around. Explain what it is that you want to accomplish and then we can see if there's a way to do it, rather than showing us something you want to use and asking if it exists.

Comment: I want to create a kids toy, where is a CPLD (like GAL22V10D) taken as a sample, so I need to shorts column lines and row lines with some big connector. It will be most obvious and accessibly if the user stick this big connector into the holes.

Comment: @Arseniy Okay, can you edit your question to include a detailed description of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Arseniy I still don't understand what the 1/4" telephone jack doesn't accomplish that this custom banana plug would. 1/4" jacks and plugs are cheap and available and lock in place to boot. They're also huge which is perfect for a kid's toy. Lots of strain relief options exist, cloth cables, you name it. The open concept switchcraft jacks could easily be used across two boards. You could even use a mono jack on each board and just solder it high enough that the tip of the plug on the top board can lock into the jack on the bottom board.

Comment: [Jacks that let the plug go all the way through](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/keystone-electronics/575-4/318493) do exist and are quite cheap.